# java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, keycloak, resteasy

I'm getting this error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader

**code:**

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
        .serverUrl(serverUrl)
        .realm(realm)
        .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .username("user")
        .password("password")
        .resteasyClient(
                new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl()
                    .connectionPoolSize(20)
                    .build()
                )
        .build();
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.0</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for your help

PS: There is one post about it, but the person at this time was not using the same maven library. They was older

Comment: Are these client or server dependencies? What is the target runtime?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins , That's the code and dependencies written in the resource server to access the keycloak server.

Comment: I'm not a keycloak expert, but it could be a version mismatch. I know WildFly 24 is on RESTEasy 3.15.1.Final which is quite different than RESTEasy 4.7.x.

Comment: Definitely, it's a problem of version. It's crazy they did resolved it since all this time. Thanks a lot for your help